Salesforce Opportunity Stage bypass automation
As an admin, I would like to understand the use of flow to by pass stages/phases on an opportunity.
The scenario is that for an opportunity there are 3 level of approvals in place with about 10 stages/phases from identification to won.
The ask is to bypass an approval process if the opportunity type is only 1st and 3rd Approval based and opportunity stages/phases gets updated accordingly.
Pipeline phases - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
Opportunity type - Okay, Think, manage.
Approvals stage - Okay, Think, manage.
The opportunity is at 3 pipeline phase and approved okay.. not think approval is not required since this is a manage approval opportunity for which approvals will start at phase 6. The automation should change the pipeline phase looking at approval type.
Thanks
I tried flow but seems I am missing a step.
